# Making a graphene based conductive ink

Tags: materials-design, materials-engineering, graphene, materials-informatics

I want to make a graphene-based conductive ink with cyclohexanone pr terpinol as the solvent and ethyl cellulose as the binder. How can I do that?

Comment: I searched patent databases years ago, and found several entry like this.

Comment: I might have asked Camps if he could write an answer, but since the asker hasn't signed in for 7 months, I think it's better to just close this as abandoned, and reopen it if he comes back and requests it.